# The "posts percentage" for tags - not easily enough understood

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page, tooltips

On my profile page, for each tag, I see a figure entitled "Posts %". I'm not quite clear on what that means - and the tooltip does not seem to exhibit something which adds up to that percentage in a straightforward manner.

**Edit:** Ok, I saw the MSE post and now I know what this means, but frankly - I'm not sure I would have guessed it myself.

So, I hereby suggest that **The tooltip for Posts% be expanded so as to clearly explain what percentage appears there.**.

Comment: MSO dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290358/what-does-posts-mean-under-top-tags/

Comment: @Kendra: I'll rephrase.